How do I initialize a derived-type variable?
How do I initialize a derived-type variable?
PS. I'm an old F77 programmer, with decent knowledge of OOP using C#, but new to "derived-types" in Fortran. A MS student wrote a large code and left. It worked when compiled with Intel 11 (that I cannot longer use), but it throws errors with Intel 19 (that I can use, in a larger project). I am trying to bring it back to life.  Here is a MWE of the problem I am having while trying to understand the student's code. Using Intel 11 is not an option.
program DerivedType
! investigate lines of code from large code "fabrics" that I do not understand

use strength_mod_test

! define and initialize array X
double precision, dimension(6) :: X = (/1,2,3,4,5,6/) ! just data, not PARAMETER. Values can be modified in the code.

! type (object) definition
type One  
    double precision :: small(6) ! the data in this type 
    ! pointer :: Ff(:,:) ! Pointer is not permitted as a statement within a derived-type-def.
end type One
type TxT
    double precision :: small(3,3) ! so that any var of type "type" has the correct size %small, depending of the "type" 
end type Txt
! Why the constructor is not inside the type definition. 
! Because "pointer" is not permitted inside a type def.
! You have to write the constructor outside the type def. 

! Variables must be defined before any executable code.  
! Define variables of type "type" using a constructor. 
! Cannot be defined inside the type if "pointer" is used. 
! "Type" constructor outside the type def. Note the () 
type(One), pointer :: Ff(:,:), Fw(:,:), sigmaf123(:,:), sigmaw123(:,:) 
type(TxT), pointer :: Df(:,:), Dw(:,:), Omega_f(:,:), Omega_w(:,:)

! local variables
integer i,j

! Initialize type variables
! Df is of type TxT, and in type TxT, small is (3,3)
! Df%small = 0 ! A component cannot be an array if the encompassing structure is an array.[SMALL]
! so I do this
do i=1,3
    do j=1,3
        Df(i,j)%small = 0.d0    ! why access violation?!
    enddo
end do
!    TYPE (TxT) :: Df_new = TxT (Df = 0)    does not work either

! I can't execute next statement until I initialize Df(i,j)%small and signf123(i,j)%small
Ff(i,j)%small = F_function (X, Df(i,j)%small, sigmaf123(i,j)%small)

end program

below is the module strength_mod_test:
module strength_mod_test
contains
function F_function (R, D, sig)
    double precision, dimension(6) :: F_function            ! rank=1
    double precision, dimension(6), intent(in) :: R, sig    ! rank=1       
    double precision, dimension(3,3), intent(in) :: D       ! rank=2
    
    F_function = 0.d0
    
    if (D(1,1) == 0.d0 .AND. sig(1) > 0.d0) then
        F_function(1) = sig(1)/R(1)
    end if

    if (D(2,2) == 0.d0 .AND. sig(2) > 0.d0) then
        F_function(2) = sig(2)/R(2)
    end if
    
    if (D(3,3) == 0.d0 .AND. sig(3) > 0.d0) then
        F_function(3) = sig(3)/R(3)
    end if
    
    if (D(2,2) == 0.d0 .OR. D(3,3) == 0.d0) then
        F_function(4) = abs(sig(4))/R(4)
    end if
    
    if (D(3,3) == 0.d0) then
        F_function(5) = abs(sig(5))/R(5)
    end if
    
    if (D(2,2) == 0.d0) then
        F_function(6) = abs(sig(6))/R(6)
    end if
            
end function F_function
end module


Several problems.  1. Pointers have to point to something.  Just using a pointer that doesn't point anywhere  will give you a segv.  2. Whatever you use in your function should be initialized.

Although you say "MWE", this is a long way from being minimal for what you appear to be asking about. It would be a lot easier to answer if you can cut down your code and be more precise about what you are trying to do. (Essentially, your questions appear to be written in the form of comments in the code.) You are also asking many different things: POINTER statements aren't allowed in a derived type definition, but POINTER statements are not the only way to give something the POINTER attribute. You're missing allocation, and I've no idea how important (the wrong) Df%small = 0 is to you.

Please also note that "defined" and "initialized" mean specific things in Fortran, so the colloquial, but different, use that you have here may also lead to confusion when you read an answer or related topics.

The variable X is both "declared" and "initialized" in the same line. Is that the correct language to use here?

Thanks to the comments, it is obvious that I forgot to allocate the pointers, and also forgot to properly initialize the type variables. The portion of code below addresses all of that.
! local variables
integer i,j
double precision, dimension(3,3) :: D_in=0.d0 ! used to initialize variables of type TxT, bec. the're 3x3 

! define and initialize array X
double precision, dimension(6) :: X = (/1,2,3,4,5,6/) ! just data, not PARAMETER. Values can be modified in the code.
integer sv ! to check if allocation/deallocation was successful

! Allocate and initialize type variables
allocate(Ff(nf, nw),STAT=sv);   if (sv /= 0) then; pause "sv/=0"; endif
allocate(Df(nf, nw),STAT=sv);   if (sv /= 0) then; pause "sv/=0"; endif
allocate(sigmaf123(nf, nw),STAT=sv);    if (sv /= 0) then; pause "sv/=0"; endif
! Df%small = 0 ! A component cannot be an array if the encompassing structure is an array.[SMALL]
! Solution: Df is of type TxT, & in type TxT, small is (3,3)
! Thus, each i,j element in Df must be initialized with a 3x3 matrix. 
do i=1,3        ! nf
    do j=1,3    ! nw
        Df(i,j)%small = D_in     ! 3x3 matrix of 3x3 matrices.
    enddo
end do

do i=1,3        ! nf
    do j=1,3    ! nw
        Ff(i,j)%small = F_function (X, Df(i,j)%small, sigmaf123(i,j)%small)
    enddo
enddo

